# Lista desplegable con busqueda javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, web, desarrollo

Estoy intentando realizar una lista desplegable con busqueda incluida. He logrado insertar el valor del elemento seleccionado en un textarea pero al editar el textarea la funcion no sigue activandose...

Lo intente primero con un campo input pero no me funciono.

Al momento de recoger el valor del textarea de un form me va a tomar el texto o el atributo value que le asigne? Pienso agregarlo luego a un form para traer la lista con otros valores.

Gracias de antemano.

```js
function aggpd(){
  let container =document.getElementById('lp');
  let arrpd = {'0001':"PAI",'0002':'PET'}
  
  /*for(key in arrpd){
    let pd = document.createElement('p');
    pd.setAttribute('value',key)
    pd.setAttribute('class','pd')
    pd.textContent = arrpd[key]
    container.append(pd)
  }*/
  
  for(i=0; i<200; i++){
    let pd = document.createElement('p');
    pd.setAttribute('value',i)
    pd.setAttribute('id',i)
    pd.setAttribute('class','pd')
    pd.textContent = 'Valor'+i;
    pd.addEventListener("click",test)
    container.append(pd)
  }
  
}

aggpd()

function test(e){
  let inp = document.getElementById('sr');
  let val =e.currentTarget.textContent;
  inp.textContent =  val;
}
```

```css
.bp{
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
  width:178.5px;
  height:28.5px;
  resize: none;
}
.lp{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:45px;
  left:10px;
  border-width:1px;
  border-style: solid;
  width:183.45px;
  height:100px;
  overflow: scroll;
 
  
}
.pd{
  margin-top: -1px;
}

.pd:hover{
  background-color:grey;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <textarea class="bp" value="a" rows="1" cols="1" id="sr">
      </textarea>
      <div class="lp" id="lp">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomando un **textarea** y un **div** di con la siguiente solución:

Los valores que contine la lista son una combinación de la palabra **valor** y un número del **0** al **499**

```js
 function aggpd(){
  let container =document.getElementById('lp');
 
  
  for(i=0; i<500; i++){
    let pd = document.createElement('p');
    pd.setAttribute('value',i)
    pd.setAttribute('id',i)
    pd.setAttribute('class','pd')
    pd.textContent = 'Valor '+i;
    pd.addEventListener("click",test)
    container.append(pd)
  }
  
}

aggpd()

function test(e){
  let inp = document.getElementById('sr');
  let el = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("value");

  let lpd = document.getElementById('lp');
  lpd.style.display = "none";
 
  let val =e.currentTarget.textContent;
  inp.value =  val;
  inp.setAttribute("value",el)
}


function ev(){
  let bsearch = document.getElementById("sr").addEventListener("input",re)

  
}
ev()





function re(e){
  let input = e.currentTarget.value;
  let pdss = document.getElementsByClassName('pd');
  let lpd = document.getElementById('lp');

  if(input == ""){
    lpd.style.display = "none";
  }else{
    if(lpd.style.display.value != "block"){
    lpd.style.display = "block";
  }

  
  for(let r of pdss){
    r.style.display = "none";
  }
  
  let rg = new RegExp(`${input}`, "i");
 
  for(let prod of pdss){
    let txt = prod.textContent;
    if(rg.test(txt) == true){
      
      prod.style.display = "block"
      
      
    }
  }
  }
  
}
```

```css
.bp{
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
  width:178.5px;
  height:28.5px;
  resize: none;
  
}


.lp{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:45px;
  left:10px;
  border-width:1px;
  border-style: solid;
  width:183.45px;
  height:100px;
  overflow: scroll;
 
  
}
.pd{
  
  margin-top:-1px;
}

.pd:hover{
  background-color:#767676;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="bp" value="" rows="1" cols="1" id="sr"></textarea>
<div class="lp" id="lp"></div>
```